# Can some one tell me how I can get out of this error

Tags: python, pygame

I am Learning pygame in Python from a course and when I tried to initialize super class i.e. `pygame.sprite.Sprite` I am getting it done wrong.

Please help me. Can someone tell me how can I initialize the parent class?

**Edit :**

Program is a follows that I explained :

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:pygame

import sys,random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

WHITE =[255, 255, 255]
RED =[255, 0, 0]
GREEN =[0, 255, 0]
BLUE =[0, 0, 255]
BLACK =[0, 0, 0]

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,colour,width,height):
         super(pygame.sprite.Sprite()).__init__()
         self.image = pygame.Surface(width,height)
         self.image.fill(colour)
         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

pygame.init()

size = [800,1250]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range (40):
    block = Block(BLACK,20,20)

    block.rect.x = random.randrange(size[0])
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(size[1])

    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprite_list.add(block)

player = Block(RED,20,20)   
all_sprite_list.add(player) 



clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while True:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    player.rect.x = pos[0]
    player.rect.y = pos[1]         

    hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,block_list,True)    
    all_sprite_list.draw(screen)       
    clock.tick(60)    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Here is [a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYZua.jpg):

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Comment: done now programm is in text

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Added an link down there if screenshot of error have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) has to be a type rather than an object. Note `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` creates an object.

A typical superclass call in this case is either

```py
super(Block,self).__init__()
```

or just

```py
super().__init__()
```

More information is provided in the python documentation, [9.5. Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) respectively [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

---

The first parameter to [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) has to be a [Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) which contains the width and height of the surface. So it has to be:

<s>`self.image = pygame.Surface(width,height)`</s>

```py
self.image = pygame.Surface((width,height))
```

---

Change the constructor of `Blocks` as follows, to solve the issue:

```py
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,colour,width,height):
         super().__init__() # or: super(Block,self).__init__()
         self.image = pygame.Surface((width,height))
         self.image.fill(colour)
         self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 23, you instantiated pygame.surface when you should have instantiated pygame.Surface (Surface with an uppercase S).

Source:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html